# Unable to connect websocket java client on Heroku Node.js server

Tags: java, node.js, heroku, jetty

I'm trying to connect my Java client to Node.js server on Heroku via Jetty websockets, but there is no connection. @OnWebSocketConnect method doesn't execute.

```
    WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient();
    SimpleEchoSocket socket = new SimpleEchoSocket();

    try {
        client.start();
        URI echoUri = new URI(destUri);
        ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
        client.connect(socket, echoUri, request);
        socket.awaitClose(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            client.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: There are no exceptions, but there is no connection also, as I said method  onConnect is never getting invoked

Comment: Could you post the Node.js code as well? The code above doesn't really tell me enough to be of any help (I'm not experienced in Java, but I do understand Node). A dropped connection could be on both ends, as well as server configuration. There's a lot of variables here.